# Missing Tag Sets in Profile Tags Field

Tags: profile, tags

I am using CiviCRM 4.7.23 (on drupal & wordpress)

Is it normal that Tag sets (custom ones) are not showing when rendering the Tag(s) Field in profiles?

I've reproduced the case on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ :

1. I've created a Tag Set for Contacts named "Sector" (with two tags)
2. I've added Tag(s) field to the reserved profile "New Organization"
3. If you check the preview of the profile only the main tag list is showing.
   Link to the preview http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/uf/group?action=preview&id=5&field=0&context=group

As I wanted to use tags in profiles forms, for the moment the solutions I have is to move my tags from the custom Tags set to main Tag tree or create a custom field.

Thank you for your help!